# sed command to append string inside the double qoutes

Tags: sed

I want to update a file on remote linux server. For this i am using sed command. in that i have to first search that line then update value

i have file with following content:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ankur"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

so using sed command i have to append sharma in double qoutes
means after execution line will be  grub_cmdline_linux = "ankur sharma"

i have tried this command

```
sed -i 's+\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.*\)+\1 sharma+g' '/etc/default/grub.bak'
```

by this command sharma is appending at the end of the line but it should be append inside the double qoutes

Expected output:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ankur sharma"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be something like

```
sed '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/s/"$/ sharma"/' /etc/default/grub.bak
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[^"]*/& sharma/' file
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ankur sharma"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```